# Proving it's a martingale and more conditions.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, solution-verification, expectation, martingales

Let $(X_{n})_{n>0}$ be a sequence of random variables in $[0, 1]$ and assuming that ($X_{0}=a)        \epsilon [0, 1]$ then:

$Pr\left(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n}\right)=1-X_{n}$ and  $Pr\left(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}}\right)=X_{n}$.

$a)$ Prove that  $(X_{n})_{n>0}$ is a martingale according to the natural filtration and it's almost sure that it converges to a RV $Z$.

$b)$ Demonstrate that $E([X_{n+1}-X_{n}]^2)=\frac{1}{4}E[X_{n}(1-X{n})]$.

$c)$ Calculate $E[Z(1-Z)]$.

$d)$ Define the law of $Z$.

This was my attempt to solve this:

$a)$

To prove  $(X_{n})_{n>0}$ is a martingale you need to prove that

$i)$ $E[|X_{n}|]=E[X_{n}]<\infty$

This is proven by the definition of  $X_{n}\epsilon[0, 1]$

$ii)$ $X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable.

This is proven by being the natural filtration.

$iii)$ $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=X_{n}$

Noticing that $Pr(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n})+Pr(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n})=1$ so $Pr(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n})+Pr(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n})$ is the density function for $X_{n+1}$

Then $$E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=\frac{X_{n}}{2}Pr(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n}) +\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}Pr(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n})$$ $$=\frac{X_{n}}{2}(1-X_{n})+\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}X_{n}$$ $$=\frac{X_{n}-X_{n}^2}{2}+\frac{X_{n}^2+X_{n}}{2}=X_{n}$$ proving is martingale.

Now, I don't know how to prove the convergence.

$b)$

Let $$E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=E[(X_{n+1}^2-2X_{n+1}X_{n}+X_{n}^2)|\mathcal{F}_{n}]$$ $$=E[X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]-2E[X_{n+1}X_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]+E[X_{n}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}$$ $$=E[X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]-2E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]E[X_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]+E[X_{n}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}$$

And because it's a martingale we can assume that $$=E[X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]-2X_{n}^2+E[X_{n}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]$$

then applying expectancy on both sides $$E[E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2]]=E[E[X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]-2X_{n}^2+E[X_{n}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]$$  $$E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2]=E[X_{n+1}^2]-2E[X_{n}^2]+E[X_{n}^2]$$ $$=E[X_{n+1}^2-X_{n}^2]$$ $$=E[X_{n+1}^2]-E[X_{n}^2]$$
And again applying conditional expectancy we have $$E[E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]]=E[(E[X_{n+1}^2]-E[X_{n}^2])|\mathcal{F}_{n}]$$ $$=E[E[X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]]-E[E[X_{n}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]]$$

And from $a)$ we can see that $$E[X_{n+1}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=(\frac{X_{n}}{2})^2(1-X_{n})+(\frac{X_{n}+1}{2})^2X_{n}$$ $$=\frac{X_{n}^2}{4}(1-X_{n})+\frac{X_{n}^2+2X_{n}+1}{4}X_{n}$$ $$=\frac{X_{n^2}-X_{n}^3+X_{n}^3+2X_{n}^2+X_{n}}{4}$$ $$=\frac{1}{4}(3X_{n}^2+X_{n})$$

then $$E[E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]]=E[\frac{1}{4}(3X_{n}^2+X_{n})]-E[E[X_{n}^2|\mathcal{F}_{n}]]$$ $$E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2=\frac{1}{4}E[(3X_{n}^2+X_{n})]-E[X_{n}^2]$$ $$=\frac{1}{4}(3E[X_{n}^2]+E[X_{n}]-4E[X_{n}^2)$$ $$=\frac{1}{4}(X_{n}-X_{n}^2)$$ $$=\frac{1}{4}(X_{n}(1-X_{n}))$$

This is as far as I could go, if anyone can tell me if I'm right with what I've done, and also could help me being more formal at the demonstrations I would appreciate it a lot. Also anyone that could help me finish the rest of the subsection step-by-step would be really appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

a) Note that $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a non-negative martingale which is bounded in $L^2$. There are [martingale convergence theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems) which ensure that under these assumptions there exists a random variable $Z$ such that $X_n \to Z$ almost surely and $X_n \to Z$ in $L^2$.

c) Use b) and the fact that $X_n \to Z$ in $L^2$.

d) Use c) to deduce that $Z \cdot (1-Z) =0$ almost surely. Hence, $Z \sim p \delta_0 + (1-p) \delta_1$ for some $p \in [0,1]$. In order to find $p$,  note that $\mathbb{E}Z = \mathbb{E}X_0 = a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I would really appreciate a step-by-step solution, I've been struggling with this one long enough, For starters, I had found that martingales convergence theorems before, but I want to make a full demonstration of everything, and demonstrating that theorem, for me, is a headbreaker.

Comment: For $c)$ i guess you're meaning something like $$E(Z(1-Z))=E[(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n})(1-(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}))]$$ $$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[X_{n}(1-X_{n})]$$ $$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}4E[(X_{n+1}-X_{n})^2]$$ $$=4E[((\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_{n+1})-(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}X_{n}))^2]$$ $$=4E[(Z-Z)^2]$$ $$=4E[0]=0$$

And for $d)$ I'm really lost, so if you could help me I would really appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @IanLev c): That's exactly what I meant. d): Recall that $\int Y \, d\mathbb{P} = 0$ implies $Y=0$ (almost surely) for any non-negative random variable $Y$. Use the pointwise convergence and c) to conclude that $Z \sim p \delta_0 + (1-p) \delta_1$ for some $p \in [0,1]$. Finally use that $\mathbb{E}Z=\mathbb{E}X_0=a$ in order to determine $p$.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm gonna try doing $d)$ with your hints :)

Comment: @IanLev Did you succeed in proving d)? :)

Comment: Not really, I start doing this:

Comment: From $c)$ we can see that $$E[Z(1-Z)]=0$$ $$=E[Z-Z^2]=0$$ $$=E[Z]=E[Z^2]$$ But then I cannot see how to use the hints you gave me, unless you mean something like if $Y \sim (Z-Z^2)$ then  i can apply the definition of expectancy you used as hint, but I can't see where to go next. :/

Comment: @IanLev Note that $\mathbb{E}(Z \cdot (1-Z))=0$ implies $Z \cdot (1-Z)=0$ almost surely since $0 \leq Z \leq 1$ (as $0 \leq X_n \leq 1$ and $X_n \to Z$ a.s.).

Comment: I'm just doing this intuitively, but $Z$ a.s. has to have a similar distribution as $X_{n}$ so my guesses are that $Z \sim a\delta_{0} +(1-a)\delta_{1}$ where the $\delta_{0}, \delta_{1}$ are similar to $Pr\left(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}}{2}|\mathcal{F}_{n}\right),   Pr\left(X_{n+1}=\frac{X_{n}+1}{2}|\mathcal{F_{n}}\right)]$ or something like that? I feel like I'm dumb as a rock ._.

Comment: Just another thing, is this really that difficult, I'm just going the wrong directions or I'm just lacking of knowledge and expertice?
I ask this because this is the first time I encounter with a "Define the law of something" so I'm not quite sure what does the author means with this. By now with your hints, it looks like is just getting the distribution of $Z$ but this still makes me confuse. Thanks in advance, I apreciate this like you have no idea. :)

Comment: @IanLev Well, the author simply wants you to determine the distribution of $Z$. And no, it is not *that* difficult. So back to d): By $\delta_c$ I denote the Dirac measure (point measure) in $c$, i.e. if I write $Z \sim p \delta_0 + (1-p) \delta_1$ this means that $\mathbb{P}(Z=0)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(Z=1)=(1-p)$. The important thing is to understand that $\mathbb{E}(Z \cdot (1-Z))=0$ implies $Z \cdot (1-Z)=0$ almost surely. Now as $x \cdot y =0$ (for real $x,y$) if and only if $x=0$ or $y=0$, this yields that $Z \sim p \delta_0 + (1-p) \delta_1$.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard or  Dirac measure before, thanks for that, and for finding p.
You said before that $$E[Z]=E[X_{0}]=a$$ Does this happens because of the pointwise convergence? And if so, what I'm thinking is something like if we take the restricted the values of $Z \in [0, 1]$ then the lowest probability is $P(Z=0) = P(X_{0}=0)$, so there we can assure $E[Z]=E[X_{o}]=a$ so $Z \sim a\delta_{o} + (1-a)\delta_{1}$? Again, thanks for your time and pattience, it's hard to find someone willing to explain this kind of stuff and even harder to find someone that isn't jealous with their knowledge.

Comment: @IanLev I didn't find $p$, you still have to find it! :) $$\mathbb{E}Z = \mathbb{E}X_0 = a$$ holds because $X_n \to Z$ in $L^2$. Indeed, $X_n \to Z$ in $L^2$ implies $X_n \to Z$ in $L^1$ which in turn implies $\mathbb{E}X_n \to \mathbb{E}Z$ as $n \to \infty$. Now as $X_n$ is a martingale, the claim follows. In order to determine $p$ note that $Z \sim p \delta_0 + (1-p) \delta_1$ implies $$\mathbb{E}Z = p \cdot 0 + (1-p) \cdot 1 = (1-p).$$ (Your comments make me curious: Do you study mathematics?)

Comment: I'm studying Actuarial Science and since I'm not an Ace student, I do my best to learn the most I can. Also my teachers can be divided in 2 groups, The one's that have so much knowledge that is hard for them to understand the difficulty for us (stuents) of the subjects, so for them everything is trivial and questions like the one's I ask are not worth of their time, and the other part are the teachers that cannot explain properly leading to more questions and doubts, and imminetly to wrong or misleading knowlege.

Comment: And regarding about $p$, I cannot belive is that simple or I'm just going the easy way. Since $$E[Z] =a$$ and $$E[Z]= 1-p$$ $$\rightarrow p=1-a$$ really?

Comment: @IanLev Yes, that's it. :) (... and it is a pity that your teachers are not willing/able to answer your questions...)

Comment: Really thanks a lot!

Comment: @IanLev Glad I could help you. (And I really appreciate students like you, who do the exercises step by step on their own - instead of asking for full solutions.)